# Add all unversioned files to SVN

Tags: svn

I have a working copy that gets automatically committed into SVN overnight using a script.

I use the SVN command line to do so.

After a frustrating battle with Google, I have been unable to work out how to automatically add all unversioned files in the working copy to the repository before the commit.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this?

Kindness and thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
svn --force --depth infinity add .
```

Be careful, though, because this will also add any `svn:ignore`'d files.

Comment: After further testing, it seems `--depth` isn't necessary, but it can't hurt either.

Comment: the --force was what I was missing ... muchos gracias!

Comment: this will add currently ignored files too, take care!

Comment: How can we add only **Unversioned** files only But **NOT IGNORED** ?

Answer (score 31):

The accepted solution

> svn --force add .

will also add all **ignored** unversioned files. Most people likely prefer
just to add all unversioned but not ignored files.

To add all **unversioned but not ignored** files, codefox421 answer is right:

> svn st | grep '^\?' | sed 's/^\? *//' | xargs -I% svn add %

as `svn st` does not show ignored files.

Answer (score 16):

Try this one on for size - much more elegant than forcing through an svn add:

```
$ svn add `svn status|grep '\?'|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Or try this one. It accepts spaces in the path:
`svn st | grep '^\?' | sed 's/^\? *//' | xargs -I% svn add %`

Comment: I used codefox421's suggestion and added an alias to ~/.bashrc: `alias svn-add-unversioned="svn st | grep '^\?' | sed 's/^\? *//' | xargs -I% svn add %"` Now I just type `svn-a` and hit tab, enter!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `svn add` in your script for each unversioned file prior to `svn commit`—something like this for a shell script:

```
for file in `svn st | grep '^\?' | awk '{ print $2; }'`; do
    svn add $file
done
```

Comment: Eww. Using `--force` on the root of the working directory will automatically add any unversioned files underneath it.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it's very overengineered, given the alternatives :)

Comment: This fails if you have spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i need to specify :

```
 svn --force add dir/*/*/*
```

`*` is level of tree that i want to add.

Check the result with

```
svn status --no-ignore
```