# Adding files in SVN causes ignored items to be added

Tags: svn, svnignore

In my subversion repostiry i need to ignore several files and folders.
I've added **svn:ignore** properties where it needs to be.

After changes made i need to add new files into repository recursively, as there too much new stuff.
But executing `svn add * --force` causes ignored files to be added to versioning!

How can i recursivly add new files in Subversion with applying svn:ignore properties?

Comment: If you are on Linux, this SO answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20095520/1023562. If you are on Win, rewrite the script from above link to PowerShell.

Comment: I had thought that you could just use `svn add . --force` instead of using the * wildcard...but I see in that linked answer that this may also add the ignored files. I didn't expect that from reading the [svn book section on add](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) but I don't have SVN on this computer to test.