# How do I alias commands in svn?

Tags: macos, svn, version-control

I want to add some aliases for `svn` command in macOS system. For example:

```
svn ci "Some message" // equal to svn commit -m "Some message"
svn addall // equal to svn add --force * --auto-props --parents --depth infinity -q
```

What have I do to achieve this?

I am newb in svn, previously I use `git` and all aliases were created in `.gitconfig` file. Is this possible in the same way in `svn`?

***UPDATE***

Regarding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584656/5433235) note, after adding the following lines in `~/.subversion/config` file :

```
alias ciam = "commit -m" 

[alias]
ciam = commit -m
```

the command:

```
svn ciam
```

still not working.

Is it another way possible to define svn aliases?

Comment: Yes, that is what I say in the answer: the config file for svn is *not* for alias definition: aliases are at the shell level only.

Comment: So the short answer is: *no*, it is *not* possible.

Comment: It is not that I want to hear, but it solves the problem, thanks @VonC !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to define bash aliases (and not svn configs), as the ones proposed in [xentek's gist](https://gist.github.com/xentek/4108719)

```
# add everything that needs to be added based on results of svn status
alias svnadd="svn st | grep \? | awk '''{print \"svn add \"$2 }''' | bash"
```

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598968/add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn#comment35447619_10199313), for instance:

> added an alias to `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias svn-add-unversioned="svn st | grep '^\?' | sed 's/^\? *//' | xargs -I% svn add %"
```

> Now I just type `svn-a` and hit tab, enter!

In your case, you can define `alias svnaddall` to your command (mentioned in "[How do I SVN add all unversioned files to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4046862/6309)").

---

Note: that are [subversion config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617826/6309) (`~/.subversion/config` or `/etc/subversion/config`), but it won't include alias definition.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful but it's a kind of a workaround I think. If there is no such a thing like `.svnconfig` I will accept your answer